# Showing BEL character in c#

Tags: c#

BEL character isn't shown in Console window in Visual Studio

```
char character7 = (char)7;
Console.WriteLine(character7);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Likewise BS character

```
char character8 = (char)8;
Console.WriteLine(character8);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok, what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
     char character7 = (char)7;
     Console.WriteLine("Is the char control character? {0}", Char.IsControl(character7));
}
```

And the output is:

> Is the char control character? True

So for conclusion the BEL character is a control character.

> Control characters are formatting and other non-printing characters,
>   such as ACK, BEL, CR, FF, LF, and VT.

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) you can't print BEL character and all other control characters.

Comment: Good link in the microsoft, I didn't know that. I deleted my answer.